# Not sure how to debug these errors in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

following are the errors being returned 'Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.'
This error is specifically telling me to review the 'Dates' and 'Canvas' element defs in the code. Also, says to check the render method of 'App.'

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import "react-native-dates";
import { Dates } from "react-native-dates";
import {moment} from "moment";
import {Chart} from "react-native-chartjs";
import {Canvas} from 'react-native-canvas';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.chart = null;
    this.state = {
      startDate: null,
      endDate: null,
      focusedInput: null,
      dates: []
    };
    this.handleDatesChange = this.handleDatesChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFocusChange = this.handleFocusChange.bind(this);
    this.updateChart = this.updateChart.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.chart = new Chart(this.node, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "# of Likes",
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }

  handleDatesChange({ startDate, endDate }) {
    let dates = [];
    for (
      let m = moment(startDate);
      m.diff(moment(endDate), "days") <= 0;
      m.add(1, "days")
    ) {
      dates.push(m.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    }
    this.setState({ startDate, endDate, dates }, () => {
      let data = this.randomData(this.state.dates.length);
      this.updateChart(this.state.dates, data);
    });
  }

  handleFocusChange(focusedInput) {
    this.setState({ focusedInput });
  }

  updateChart(labels, data) {
    this.chart.data.labels = labels;
    this.chart.data.datasets[0].data = data;
    this.chart.update();
  }

  randomData(length) {
    let data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      data.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    }
    return data;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} >
        <Dates
          startDateId="startDate"
          endDateId="endDate"
          startDate={this.state.startDate}
          endDate={this.state.endDate}
          onDatesChange={this.handleDatesChange}
          focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput}
          onFocusChange={this.handleFocusChange}
        />
        <Canvas ref={node => (this.node = node)} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
  },
});
```

Comment: What is the version of react-native?

Comment: your second line looks wrong. You're importing react-native-dates without specifying where from or what you're importing from it. Try commenting out that line and just using the next line, the one that says import Dates from react-native-dates. Also ensure your components have been exported

Comment: it's "react-native": "0.63.3",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import your `Dates` and `Canvas` as default modules:

```
import Dates from 'react-native-dates';
import Canvas from 'react-native-canvas';
```